# Populist badge shouldn't be awarded for an old answer losing its checkmark

Tags: feature-request, badges

> [image: Populist:]
>   <sup>Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x</sup>
>   <sup>Awarded for: [How can I check if multiplying two numbers in Java will cause an overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657834/how-can-i-check-if-multiplying-two-numbers-in-java-will-cause-an-overflow/1657868#1657868)</sup>

Recently I was awarded the [populist badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/populist) for my +31 answer outscoring the +11 accepted answer. I swelled with pride with the thought of adding another golden trophy to my mantle.

But my joy was shortlived, for clicking the badge revealed a bitter truth. This is no triumph of populism over privilege. No thumb at the nose of foolishly awarded checkmark. Nay, it is the reverse. An answer I wrote many years ago, once a proud champion, has been stripped of its title by a newer, better answer. The underdog has triumphed. The scrappy upstart has won. David has slain Goliath.

Yet, Goliath was awarded the gold badge. For losing. What cruel mockery is this?

---

The badge was correctly awarded according to its list of criteria, but I didn't deserve a badge for this. The badge criteria should be refined somehow. Maybe by comparing the ages of the answers? I'm not sure exactly.

If anything, @bcoughlan should have been awarded something for dethroning an old answer.

Comment: Not sure what the solution is. The scenario certainly doesn't seem to match the intention of the badge. Maybe you could do something where votes that count for this badge have to be accumulated while another answer is the accepted one. Or in other words, votes don't count for this badge if your answer is currently the accepted one. But that would probably be overly complicated.

Comment: Or you don't award the badge if the answer was once accepted and has been unaccepted.

Comment: Maybe Steve McLeod would deserve something too for maintaining and keeping up-to-date a 5-year-old question, and replacing the old (but still valid?) answer for a newer better answer

Comment: I wonder how many of the existing 7.6k users received the badge this way. i've been very close to it for 3 years now, the 2x requirement keeps it just barely out of my reach!

Comment: This is what happens when questions don't specify a language version -- they become moving goalposts.  Not fair to anyone involved.  What bcoughlan should have done was create a new question about Java 8 and edit the old one to say Java 7 (or 6) and include a link to the new one.

Comment: @martin That's probably a better approach. Certainly simpler, and it mostly addresses the same problem. The only downside is that it would trigger if the answer was accepted only briefly. But that's an exceptional case within a scenario that might be reasonably rare already.

Comment: Agreed. It just happened to me in [Length of string in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17368090/1983854) where my one-liner got unaccepted in favour of a better, newer answer. I think the most rewardable thing here is the new answer, not the old one that lost its position over time.

Answer (score -4):

I think fixing this badge would be as simple as requiring that the highly-voted answer was posted after the accepted answer.

Comment: So if the highly-voted answer was posted just one second before the accepted one, then it doesn't deserve the badge?

Comment: But those are accepted use cases for this badge.