# A badge for answers that beats an old accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

I think that a good idea for a new badge would be what I will call **overrun**.

It would be awarded when:

1. an answer is accepted on a question, then
2. someone else (I'll call him person1) comes along and gives another answer,
3. person1's answer is then assigned the accepted answer and
4. the new accepted answer is up-voted n times (5 maybe?) to make sure this is a good answer, then
5. person1 gets the badge.

The reason I think this will help the community is because it will encourage people to answer a question after an answer was already accepted.

I tried to create [a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/394675/overrun-badge) for this, but as is said in an answer (and comments) to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269687/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-an-accepted-answer-has-been-re-assigned) I asked, it didn't work (let me now if you get one that works right).

I am not sure if this would be silver or gold (I think it is too hard to get for bronze. I could be wrong). What are your two cents on this?

Comment: Seems fine. When we have badges like tumbleweed and necromancer, we could do with this. Although I am not sure if it will help people in any way.

Comment: *to hard to get for bronze* - [Mortarboard](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard) is bronze and for some of us, that's extremely hard to get. I do however like the idea.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ. True, also the [Generalist](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15/generalist) badge has only 619 awarded and is way harder then some gold badges. It was just a thought.

Comment: How about calling it "upstart" or "NKOTB"?

Comment: It encourages late answers, a problem that was already big enough to require a review queue.  Making that queue bigger can't be the goal of that badge.  It will also re-activate questions that don't need an answer, pushing it ahead of questions that do.  And make answerers despair at an OP that has left the building.  Three strikes against.  The latter is the trickiest problem, you can't do anything to make the OP show up to accept the answer.  Drop that requirement and you already have the Necromancer and Populist badges.

Comment: Would a badge create enough incentive? I recently answered an old javascript question by improving the speed of the top answer from O(n^2) to O(n), but since it's rather old it hasn't really received any votes. My incentive was due to this question being rather common and myself having encountered it a few times. I don't think a badge would alter my incentive by much.

Comment: @HansPassant Late answers aren't a bad thing, bad late answers are a bad thing. But they are just as bad as any other kind of bad answer. So unless we are going to discourage answering altogether, I don't see how that part of your logic fits.

Comment: @TinyGiant steelmanning Hans, I think he's saying that late answers on old, popular questions are *particularly likely* to be crap or merely redundant. Note that since you're not at 10k rep yet you don't see most of these, because they're likely to get flagged as VLQ and deleted; once you hit 10k rep you'll see that most popular questions on the site have a slew of bad deleted answers at the bottom, occasionally numbering in the dozens. So his argument makes some sense in principle... but I'm not convinced the extra incentive will change much in practice.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ: ask 100 questions, accept them in one day and - voila, Mortarbadge is here (I vote this comment for the worst advice ever given on meta). Do this 50 times and you are epic.

Comment: @JanTuroň. HA, then loose a bunch of reps due to **serial questioning** (well, I don't know if *that* exists).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't like the naming (there'd have to be some more ideas here) but the idea isn't half bad.

Updating stale Q&A's is a big issue on SO, and it will likely stay that way. Encouraging people to find questions with outdated answers, and provide better answers, looks like a good thing.

The badge shouldn't be made dependent on the check mark, though. It is arbitrary, and that rule would be too easy to game.

The rule could be that an answer that comes in n days after the highest-voted other answer (which has to have at least x votes) and garners at least y votes, gets the badge.

Comment: Agreed. The checkmark thing would probably make this another *you've to be insanely lucky to get this badge* badge :P

Comment: I like the idea!

Comment: What's the difference with necromancer badge? Maybe some gold badge could exist. Grey badge (pardon, silver) is not so shiny.

Comment: @Jan that's a fair point - but the difference would be that there would have to be a highly upvoted old answer, which the necromancer badge doesn't call for. Seems worthy enough as it's an added difficulty. Perhaps a gold badge version for necromancer though, good idea

Comment: The phrase "[isn't half bad](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/this-isnt-half-bad.680927/)" can mean "fairly good" or "fairly bad", depending on where someone is from. I assume you mean "fairly good"? :)

Comment: @psmears exactly! :)

Answer (score 16):

The existing [Populist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/populist) badge goes in that direction:

> Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Maybe a silver badge with slightly weakened requirements would fit your description? (Disregarding the condition of changing the accepted status.)

I'm actually not sure if there is a history of acceptedness of answers in the posts table, therefore this part might be tricky to implement.

Comment: So answer requires min 20 votes for this badge? isn't it? I think it should be lowered to 10 .

Comment: @SomnathMuluk - From the description it seems like 11 would already be enough if the accepted answer had 0 score. Then both conditions are met - your answer's score is bigger by more than 10 and the score is bigger by more than 2 times. 1 and 12 would also fit. 20 and 31 would not fit, as the score is not bigger by more than 2 times.

Comment: The accepted answer needs a score of *more than 10* meaning that the Populist badge requires an answer score of at least 2 * 11 + 1 = 23.

Comment: [The populist badge is flawed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290455/343721)

Answer (score 2):

I like the spirit of this proposal. Quite a lot of newcomers blindly accept the first answer they get no matter how poor it is. If the question was worthless to begin with, then so it shall be, but if the question actually has merit, the fact that there already is an accepted answer stops many people from adding a better one because “the problem is already solved”. This is not quite in alignment with the idea of Stack Overflow.

I would suggest the following criteria for the new badge.

- You posted an answer to a question that already had an accepted answer with a non-negative score for at least *N* days.
- Your answer rates at least *M*.
- Your answer rates higher than *α* times the rate of originally accepted answer.

Reasonable parameters for a bronze badge seem *N* = 1, *M* = 5 and *α* = 2. Maybe higher levels for silver and gold.

Whether or not your answer eventually becomes accepted should be immaterial because, as mentioned above, this situation most often occurs with OPs that don't put much thought into what answer they accept and so they'll be even less likely to come back and re-consider their choice at a later point.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a bad idea, and I can see how the community could profit from good new answers to improve outdated ones.

But I fear, that such a badge would attract a lot of low quality late-answers. The workload in the LA-review-queue would increase dramatically as loads of people dig old questions to reanswer.

Comment: That's a strange this I've seen. I see questions sometimes with some amazing answers with a number of up-votes, and then a latecomer comes in and posts a really basic answer which is like a minor subset of some of the better ones and offers nothing new. I don't know why people do that. :-D

Comment: They think they can use the popularity of the question to draw attention and upvotes (as if...) to their answer I guess.

Answer (score -1):

I'm making some specifics suggestions:

Top answer age >= 180 days
Accepts can substitute ceiling(50%) of your score requirement
A: top answer score
B: your answer score
C: question score

**Bronze**

25>A>5 ; B>A ; C>5

**Silver**

125>A>24 ; B>30+abs(A/2-25)

**Gold**

500>A>124 ; B>A*0.75

**Gold, super overturn**

A>500 ; B>A/2

**Also,**
a badge for those who participate:

Assist in 10 overturn awards. (bronze)